# In Eclipse BIRT, how to find elements by ID in layout view?

Tags: eclipse, birt

In Eclipse BIRT, how to find elements by ID in layout view?

For example, your report has too many elements, you want to find a specific Element Id = 1567, how can I find it easily in my Layout view? Is there an Eclipse shortcut that will find and select a specific element id; just like how word search does.

Comment: Did you ever find your answer?